# Why is there blood dripping from the middle of the wall at the end of S06E05?

Tags: the-walking-dead

At the very end of the episode 5 of season 6 of *The Walking Dead*, a growing blood trail is shown going from the middle of a wall section. It doesn't look like someone died up above because there are other horizontal bars above it that would block the flow. What is going on?

[image]

Comment: Its going to be speculation until the next episode, or the episode after that if the way they are building the suspense through the series is continued.That said we speculated that the number of zombies is piling up so much that they are squishing up against the wall, foreshadowing the walls collapse due to sheer weight of numbers.

Comment: Zombies piling up makes sense. But then I think the wall wouldn't need to collapse, they could just walk right over the dead pile and this is why characters can't kill and leave them near the walls.

Comment: Maybe pile wasn't the best choice of words. The zombies aren't creating a pile they are just pushing each other into the walls. Excuse my colloquialism  say things like piling into a bus here...

Comment: Oh I thought that would be pretty logical for them to step on each other and create a pile of bodies. Always thought it was silly that they just stood still and waved their hands in the air. Guess it depends on the kind of zombiness. In any case, this is a reasonable explanation of what could be happening. I just thought I missed some clue about it during the episode, but if it's not there, we'll have to wait for the next episodes.

Comment: I thought there was something odd about it too, it kind of creates an optical illusion. Also, I noticed it makes a brief re-appearance in a subsequent episode; shown from a different perspective, in which it's quite clearly a bullet hole. I'm unsure of its apparent significance, however.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious implication is that the herd outside the wall is now so enormous that the zombies closest to the wall are being crushed by the sheer weight of the horde behind them.

In the first episode of the season, we see something quite similar happen when the herd is being led around the bend in the road, at the point where a temporary wall was erected to direct the zombies in the desired direction.  The mass of the herd squashes the zombies who are unlucky enough to be between their colleagues and the wall, and when the herd passes, the walls are smeared with gore.

The same idea applies to Alexandria's walls.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of walkers being crushed against walls or fences by the sheer numbers behind them. One of the extras on the Blu-rays for season 3 or 4 shows a walker being literally cut into pieces by the force pushing it into the prison fence. This is why I assumed your answer is the correct one - the only question is "how long will the wall hold?"